# How to use Akka.Net Testkit with F# api?

Tags: f#, akka.net

Can somebody show an example how to use Akka.Net Testkit with F# API?
Both Akka.Net and F# are quite new to me so I don't know if it is even feasible or reasonable to write unit tests this way (F# API and Testkit).
To be more specific, quite simply I don't know how to get access to Sys with F# API. This is what I got:

```
module SocketTests
open Xunit
open Akka.TestKit
open Akka.TestKit.Internal
open Akka.TestKit.Xunit2
open Akka.FSharp

type SocketTests() =
    inherit Akka.TestKit.Xunit2.TestKit()


    [<Fact>]
    let Socket_should_change_to_connected_state_when_receiving_Connect() =
```

Ok, now I would need to get reference to Sys for spawning something and for the life of me I can't figure it out. :-(

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You would need to make your test an instance method to have access to Sys (so using `member` instead of `let`). Akka.FSharp doesn't have a dedicated testing API - if you need one you may use Akkling or just copy [Akkling.TestKit helpers](https://github.com/Horusiath/Akkling/blob/master/src/Akkling.TestKit/TestKit.fs) - it's a single file, minor type definition changes are necessary to make it working with Akka.FSharp.

Comment: Excellent, Akkling + the TestKit helpers is just what I need. Thanks for creating it.